# Чем отличается абстрактный класс от интерфейса?

Tags: c#, классы, интерфейс

Здравствуйте. В чем заключается отличие абстрактного класса от интерфейса в C#? Прошу объяснить простым языком, ибо я только недавно начал изучать программирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абстрактный класс может содержать часть реализации. В принципе, класс, абстрактный содержащий только абстрактные функции подобен интерфейсу, но есть отличие: в C# можно наследоваться только от одного класса, но реализовывать сколько угодно интерфейсов.